# How to trouble-shoot sphinx error on travis with jupyter notebooks?

Tags: travis-ci, python-sphinx

I have a PR on github (https://github.com/environmentalscience/essm/pull/101) where travis-ci gives the following error message (https://travis-ci.com/github/schymans/essm/builds/232006356):

```
reading sources... [ 40%] examples/api_features                                 

Exception occurred:

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbsphinx.py", line 1813, in apply

    env.get_domain('math').data['has_equations'][env.docname] = True

KeyError: 'has_equations'

The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-0rei5dw_.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.

A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!

The command "python setup.py build_sphinx" exited with 1.
```

examples/api_features.ipynb is a jupyter notebook, so it has something to do with rendering jupyter notebooks by sphinx, but the same command (`python setup.py build_sphinx`) works just fine on my local computer, and I have not changed this file since the last successful travis build, so I don't know how to trouble-shoot this, as I cannot access `/tmp/` on travis-ci. Does anyone have an idea what I should try?

Comment: Start by comparing your local environment to that in CI at https://travis-ci.com/github/schymans/essm/builds/232006356#L189 and https://travis-ci.com/github/schymans/essm/builds/232006356#L550.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the details about the environment used in travis-ci?

Comment: Look at the links?